# Why does Django raised IntegrityError :null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint when a form is committed?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, geoip2

I have a UserSession model that creates a session that uses the IPaddress, and city data to populate the model using Geip2. I set up a form that takes the info that I want the user to enter but get:

```
**django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint**
```

when I submit the form. The object gets created but the information that the form  takes doesn't save to the object.

## views:

```
class NewLocationCreateForm(CreateView):
        model = UserSession
        success_url = reverse_lazy('post:index')
        form_class = NewLocationCreateForm



 def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            roote = Post.objects.filter(owner =self.request.user)
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.owner = self.request.user
            user_logged_in.send(self.request.user, request=self.request)
        return super(NewLocationCreateForm, self).form_valid(form)


    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(NewLocationCreateForm, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

The problem seems to arrive at at is:

```
if form.is_valid():
 return super(NewLocationCreateForm, self).form_valid(form)
```

The user session  call of the Geoip2 seems to work but it doesn't save the form

## forms.py

```
from .models import  UserSession
from post.models import  Post
from django import forms


class NewLocationCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserSession
        fields = [
            'g_post',
            'coordinate',
            'place_name'
        ]
    def __init__(self,user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewLocationCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['g_post'].queryset = Post.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

## models.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from analytics.signals import user_logged_in
from analytics.utils import get_client_city_data, get_client_ip
from post.models import Post
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class UserSessionManager(models.Manager):
    def create_new(self, user, session_key=None, ip_address=None, city_data=None):
        session_new = self.model()
        session_new.user = user
        session_new.session_key = session_key
        if ip_address is not None:
            session_new.ip_address = ip_address
            if city_data:
                session_new.city_data = city_data
                try:
                    city = city_data['city']
                except:
                    city = None
                session_new.city = city
                try:
                    country = city_data['country_name']
                except:
                    country = None
            session_new.country = country
            session_new.save()
            return session_new
        return None

class UserSession(models.Model):
    g_post            = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User)
    coordinate      = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    place_name      = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    location_photo  = models.ImageField(upload_to='location_image', blank=True)
    updated         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    session_key     = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    ip_address      = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True, blank=True)
    city_data       = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    city            = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    country         = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    active          = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = UserSessionManager()

    def __str__(self):
        city = self.city
        country = self.country
        place_name = self.place_name
        if city and country:
            return f"{city}, {country}"
        elif city and not country:
            return f"{city}"
        elif country and not city:
            return f"{country}"
        return self.place_name    

def user_logged_in_receiver(sender, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = sender
    ip_address = get_client_ip(request)
    city_data = get_client_city_data(ip_address)
    request.session['CITY'] = str(city_data.get('city', 'New York'))
    session_key = request.session.session_key
    UserSession.objects.create_new(
                user=user,
                session_key=session_key,
                ip_address=ip_address,
                city_data=city_data
                )



user_logged_in.connect(user_logged_in_receiver)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to the fix by @solarissmoke (changing `instance.owner` to `instance.user`) which fixes IntegrityError, you are triggering `user_logged_in()` signal in the `is_valid()` method here:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if form.is_valid():
        roote = Post.objects.filter(owner =self.request.user)
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = self.request.user
        # Here you trigger signal that creates UserSession!
        user_logged_in.send(self.request.user, request=self.request)
    return super(NewLocationCreateForm, self).form_valid(form)
```

One object is therefore created with the CreateView and another one with this signal. Remove this line in `form_valid()`.

EDIT: To include data from signal, simply add this to `form_valid()` like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if form.is_valid():
        roote = Post.objects.filter(owner =self.request.user)
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = self.request.user
        instance.ip_address = get_client_ip(self.request)
        instance.city_data = get_client_city_data(instance.ip_address)
        instance.session_key = self.request.session.session_key
    return super(NewLocationCreateForm, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I ran this solution and didn't create the extra object but didn't run the ip address information. Is there a way possible to be able to get the Geip2() info as well form-input in the same object?

Comment: Move that logic to form_valid(). The same way you did for `instance.user`.

Comment: Sorry I am not understanding how to do it. could you please clarify more.  I am new at form validations and have been stuck here for quite some time

Comment: I've included that info in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `UserSession` model has no `owner` field defined, so setting that on the instance will do you no good. You probably want to do this instead:

```
if form.is_valid():
    roote = Post.objects.filter(owner =self.request.user)
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = self.request.user   # You need to set instance.user, not instance.owner
    user_logged_in.send(self.request.user, request=self.request)
    return super(NewLocationCreateForm, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: This fixed the form but created another problem. The answer does save the form, but now it makes 2 objects one with the form info and one with the Geoip2 info.

Comment: That is because your code is creating two session objects - once in the form handler and once in the `user_logged_in` signal handler. You need to refactor your logic so that its only done once.